# Passing array of character arrays to Fortran from C#

Tags: c#, interop, fortran, character, marshalling

I am attempting to call the following FORTRAN method:

```
subroutine MYMETHOD(THEARRAY)
```

with the parameter

```
CHARACTER*200  :: THEARRAY(2)
```

This seems simple enough but I ran into trouble because it is an *array* of character *arrays*. I have tried several approaches to this including marshaling (which runs in to problems because there are multiple strings.) The best I can come up with is:

```
[DllImport("theFortranDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern void MYMETHOD(THEARRAY);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StringBuilder[] theArray = new StringBuilder[2];

    theArray[0] = new StringBuilder("DataA",200);
    theArray[1] = new StringBuilder("DataB",200);

    MYMETHOD(theArray);
}
```

However, this does not work. How would I call such a method from C#? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried one StringBuilder with 400 chars?

Comment: Just tried it. The program I run it in produced the same output as my code here does. My code does run but FORTRAN complains when the data comes in. I think the data is arriving in a form FORTRAN wasn't expecting.

Comment: Did you try to pass string instead of StringBuilder?

Comment: Just tried that as well. No luck ): I have tried string[], string on its own, StringBuilder[], and StringBuilder on its own also some ref's with string[], etc. Does my code as it stands look correct? If so, I might be barking up the wrong tree. I don't currently have access to the FORTRAN's source code so it's possible the C# code is correct. The method is calling: it gets into the FORTRAN code and FORTRAN is printing a program specific warning that suggests the incoming data wasn't what it expected.

Answer (score 1):

In Fortran, `CHARACTER*200 :: THEARRAY(2)` is not an array of arrays.  It is a two element array of  scaler strings of length 200.  In other languages it might be an array of arrays.  Each Fortran string is padded on the end with blanks.  I don't know how C# handles strings ... C terminates strings with a null character.  For Fortran, that null character would have to be replaced with blanks, all the way to position 200.